# How to maintain svn revision number in svn2git migration repository

Tags: git, gitlab, svn2git

Recently one of my Svn project migrated to git using [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), is it possible to maintain old revision number in migrated git repository?

Comment: Do you mean as a comment or similar?

Comment: if possible yes or just add svn revision to it's  equivalent git revision number

Comment: git revisions are SHA checksums--you can't set those to arbitrary values to match svn revisions. The best you're likely to get is to add the original SVN commit to a comment. But I have to wonder what value that would provide.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy how we can add SVN commit to a comment while migrating existing SVN to Git?

Answer (score 0):

Use option `-m/--metadata`, See https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#options-reference.